# How can the creation of an instance happen in one component, but used in another?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, abstract-factory

Lets say there is a maven multi module project.

1. app (one jar)
2. persistence (second jar)

The aim is to make `app` "not know" about `persistence`.

In other words I want to make `Persistence` depend on `app`. Looking at the diagram bellow I don't want arrows pointing from `app` to `persistence`.

I would like to use the abstract factory (as seen also in the diagram).

So how can I get an instance of the `PersistenceImpl` in `app` component without actually specify in the `app` component `PersistenceFactoryImpl` or `PersistenceImpl`?

[image]

Comment: Why did you introduce the `app` abstraction? I understand that this is a common pattern, but objectives are different. Your own reason is the key to the answer.

Comment: You can take a look at [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to see if that fits your needs.

Comment: Because I would like `app` to be where business logic happens and `persistence` where the db stuff happens. I want `app` to be one jar, and `persistence` other jar. This way both are independently deployable and if in future the database would need to change no business logic would need to change.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, one of which is the service loader API as proposed by Slaw. If you're using frameworks, then maybe you'll be using IOC (spring, CDI, guice, ...).

Comment: Isn't what you said in the question backwards though? Shouldn't the app have instances of persistence objects and calling their methods, with the persistence not knowing anything about the app?

Comment: @Nathan Loyer, the thing is that I need in `app` implementation (created in `persistence`) of the interface from `app`.

Comment: @Cristian I'm still confused... Are you saying you need to use PersistenceFactory and Persistence interfaces in the persistence jar? If so, I'd say you should move the classes to the persistence jar. That seems like the appropriate place for them.

Comment: @Nathan Loyer, the issue with doing that is that then the `app` must depend on `persistence`. But I want it the other way around. I dont want my business logic to depend on the `persistence` at all.

Comment: @Slaw I looked into the `ServiceLoader`, but I can not make it work if the implementation is in a different module from the interface. So this works if the interface and the implementation is on the same module, but in my case they are in different modules.

Comment: The `ServiceLoader` API is designed so it can load implementations from separate modules. You just need to make sure both modules (service and service-provider) are on the classpath/modulepath and that the services are declared (how that's done is dependent on if you're using JPMS modules and is described in the Javadoc).